# What is the equivalent of PHP's InfiniteIterator in .NET?

Tags: php, .net, equivalent

I had a discussion on PHP's [InfiniteIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.infiniteiterator.php) with a friend.

Is there an equivalent of it in the .NET world?

Comment: What does it do? Is that the same as an infinite while loop?

Comment: This is what I tought I first but I also tought it would be too easy to be true. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not built-in but easy to write:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> RepeatInfinitely<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
 while(true) {
  foreach(var item in sequence)
   yield return item;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just roll your own.

```
public class InfiniteEnumerator: System.Collections.IEnumerator
{
    private System.Collections.IEnumerator  _m_enumerator;
    public InfiniteEnumerator(System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator)
    {
        _m_enumerator = enumerator;
    }

    public object Current
    {
        get { return _m_enumerator.Current; }
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (!_m_enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            _m_enumerator.Reset();
            return _m_enumerator.MoveNext();
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _m_enumerator.Reset();
    }
}
```